# docker alpine /bin/sh script.sh not found

Tags: bash, shell, docker, alpine-linux

I'm trying to build a docker image that has the **openjdk:8-alpine** as base.
The problem is when I try to execute a **script.sh**, returning me the following message:

```
/bin/sh: bin/script.sh: not found
```

The **script.sh** is in the **bin/** folder correctly, that's why I don't know what's the problem.

Anyone have any idea?

Thank you.

Comment: `bin/` is a relative path. It'd be helpful to know our current working directory, so we know *relative to what* it's being searched.

Comment: Also, the script's shebang matters. If it uses `#!/bin/bash`, you'll get this error unless `/bin/bash` actually exists. (People *shouldn't* use `.sh` extensions on bash scripts -- or scripts intended to be executed rather than sourced as a whole, for that matter -- but whether or not they should or shouldn't, people *do*, so this is very much a real-world concern).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy , very thanks for your question. I have tested here the question of **shebang** that you said and it's right. Can you put in the Answer please

Comment: I was getting the same error message, but my problem was line-endings: my shell-script used MS-DOS line endings which ash did not like. Once I converted the script file to Unix line-endings, everything worked.

Comment: @rlandster Please post that as an answer, because that solved my problem too.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Make sure the shebang on the script points to an interpreter that actually exists. Thus, if the script being invoked uses:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

...then `/bin/bash` needs to actually be installed. (Alternately, you might consider trying to port the script to work with POSIX sh, and modifying its shebang to `/bin/sh`).

Comment: As the script was not mine I decided to install the **bash** in alpine, so everything worked correctly.
Congratulations and thank you very much, it was very fast and accurate. All good for you.

Answer (score 16):

I was getting the same error message, but my problem was line-endings: my shell-script used MS-DOS line-endings which ash did not like. Once I converted the script file to Unix line-endings, everything worked.

Comment: This was my issue, underrated answer.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Was banging my head for quite long. In windows open the .sh file in Notepad++ and then use Edit -> EOL Conversion -> Unix (LF) to convert it to Unix line endings

Answer (score 3):

Also ran into this problem.
Make sure the .sh file is saved in UNIX encoding.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was UTF-8 (worked) vs UTF-8 with BOM (did not work).